# Has anyone ever been punished for making up hadiths?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, punishment

Salam everyone

There has always been a lot of discussion about which hadiths are authentic and which are not. The presence of non authentic hadiths suggests that some people modified or made up hadiths. There is always the possibility that all the non authentic ones were slowly modified over time by people unaware of it, but it seems unlikely, especially since the "uncertainty period" is quite short (the period before all of them were written in many different sources).

Has anyone ever been punished for this ? What would be/was the corresponding punishment ?

Comment: This is a good question, so far I could find people who were hadith fabricators and punished for other reasons. The main blame for hadith fabrication is that this person would be a liar, some scholars considered them as kafir. ... I hope to be able to answer your question soon.